# Highstocks Multiple x-axis or just remove date and use numbering

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to use `multiple x axis` using HighStocks.

I would like to compare the values from different date periods.

If I am not able to use multiple x-axis I would like to use numbering for example convert all dates to points and use `1,2,3,4,...`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the date-time formatting in hishstock x axis use [xAxis.labels.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.formatter)

```
xAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return this.value;
            }
        }
    }
```

If I have to guess, I assume that you data is across different time range and hence you are looking for multiple x-axis, else the other alternative you have is showing time elapsed since start to have a proper comparison for the two series, in this case you want to show raw values like you mentioned. Here you may also want to offset your data so that the values fall in a single x-range as follows

```
function offsetData(data,offset){
    //Use the given time offset or use first timestamp
    offset=offset || data[0][0];
    var newData=[];
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        newData.push([data[i][0]-offset,data[i][2]]);
    }
    return newData;
}
```

[Aligning timeseries data over different timerange | Highcharts & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/VBHks/)

Having said all the above, the option of having multiple x-axis is possible in highstock

```
 series: [
        {
        name: 'series1',
        data: data1,
        xAxis: 0},

    {
        name: 'series2',
        data: data2,
        xAxis: 1}

    ],
    xAxis: [{
        min: data1[0][0]},
    {
        min: data2[0][0]}]
```

The tooltip and x-labels may need to be reformatted to fix the multiple x-axis case, I leave that to you as exercise ;)

[Multiple X-axis | Highcharts & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/ESdmH/)